# Request body for Test History Rest API in Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-rest-api

Azure DevOps has Rest API to get [Test History](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test%20history/query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). I am not able to create the Request body for the same. I tried with few parameters but response is always 400. Did anyone manage to create the correct request body and get a response?

Request Body:

```
{
    "automatedTestName": "TestAzure.Services.Test.Results.Test_UpdateResults",
    "testCaseId": "20"
}
```

Comment: It might be easier for people to answer in case you share what you've already tried.

Comment: check your request - are you setting `Content-Type: application/json`, are actually doing a POST?  Note you may also need `Accept: application/json` too.

Comment: All request/response functions are set correctly, it gives correct response for all other Rest API requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide [`groupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test%20history/query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#testresultgroupby) into this request body:

```
{
  "groupBy": "Branch",
  "automatedTestName": "MyUnitTestProject.UnitTest1.TestMethod2",
  "testCaseId": "444"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Merlin, It looks quite odd, but why is it mandatory to provide 1. automatedTestName, 2. groupBy? What if I need to fetch History for not Automated tests..

Comment: @SandeepDhamale, This api can only work with automate test. With those non automated tests, I'm afraid you need use this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1